# How can I get my bot to ignore conversation until it is addressed directly?

Tags: node.js, botframework, slack

I want to add my bot to a Slack channel. But I want it to ignore conversation until it is addressed directly, e.g.:

```
me: hi!
me: hi!
me: @bot hi!
bot: why hello there!
```

In Microsoft Bot Framework v1, there was an option: "Listen to all messages". I don't see that option in v3. Is there a simple way to do this (i.e. without analyzing every utterance to see whether the bot was addressed)?

I'm using node.js botbuilder 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

While checking the activity text is certainly a valid option, I would instead use the Mentions capabilities provided by the library (at least in C#).

```
if (activity.GetMentions().Any(x => x.Mentioned.Name == "botName") 
{
  ...
}
```

[IMessageActivity](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/1958a3f946c2e8a540196b7d12fd15255932ce7c/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Connector/IMessageActivity.cs) has a list of [Entities](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/1958a3f946c2e8a540196b7d12fd15255932ce7c/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Connector/IMessageActivity.cs#L51). One of the possible entities coming in that list is the [Mention](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/c4dbb7183cc1c23837b6d6c8bc03fe8c54ba1f55/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Connector/Mention.cs) entity.

The [GetMentions](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/aaf86d7b0542c8e2758bf14baa6b7cc67291e390/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Connector/ActivityEx.cs#L103)() method is just a filtering the list of entities to retrieve the ones of type "mention".

### Update

Just realized that you were asking for Node.js. The Entities approach is still valid, as you can see in the [Node.js docs](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.message.html#entities). You can use `session.message.entities`.

[image]

Comment: The `session.message` object does not appear to be present for messages that match on a LUIS intent.

Answer (score 0):

The dumbest way would be to use `MessageController.cs`. The first thing you do in the Post method there would be to check that the Activity contains "@bot".

```
if (activity.Text.Contains("@bot") {
    //do your normal stuff
}
else {
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK); //ignore message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution could be the following:

```
bot.dialog('/', [
  function(session, params) {
    if(session.message.text.includes('@bot')) {
      // ... start the conversation's flow
    }
  }
]);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```js
if (session.message.address.channelId == "slack") {
  //Channel conversation
  if (session.message.address.conversation.isGroup) {
    if (session.message.text.includes("@botname")) {
      //your code
    }
    session.endDialog();
    //bot not mentioned, hence do nothing
  } else {
    //your bot reply to a DM
  }
}
```