# Botframework LUIS Slack bot only reply when name is mentioned

Tags: node.js, botframework, slack, azure-language-understanding

I'm creating a bot in slack using Microsoft's botframework and LUIS and in Node.js. Currently my bot will reply every time someone says something in the channel, however I want my bot to only reply when its name is mentioned in my slack channel. i.e. `@my-bot do this`

How would I approach this? Would I have to add slack api in order to do this?

One way I'm thinking is to create an entity to check for if `@my-bot` is mentioned, and if it is then reply and if not then don't. However, I feel there are better ways in doing this.

Thanks.

Edit:

```
dialog.onDefault(function (session) {
    var msg = new builder.Message(session).entities();
    console.log(msg);
    console.log(session);
    session.endDialog('Default Dialog');
});
```

I've looked through both `msg` and `session` and the Entities of both are empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39649451/how-can-i-get-my-bot-to-ignore-conversation-until-it-is-addressed-directly/39664223#39664223

Comment: I've looked at it but when a user mentions the bot, I do not see the `mentioned` field.

Comment: what version of botbuilder are u using?

Comment: I'm using 3.7.0. I've searched for `mentioned` and it seems only C# has it and not node.js. I just want to be able to have my bot reply only when someone mentions it and not everytime someone types in my slack channel. I could do the dumb way and just search for the words `@mybot` but I rather not do that.

Comment: You need to look for the Entities property. See the screenshot in the post I mentioned before.

Comment: I did look for it however my Entities property is empty.

Comment: please update the question with the code u are using

Comment: I've updated with the code. Thanks

Comment: But... you are creating a new message there. Am I'm missing something? You need to check the entities on the incoming message. If I recall, that means doing session.message

Comment: Yes, that was my bad. I was able to get it through `session.message.entities`.Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem! Please upvote the original answer if you can so we can close this as duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use `session.message.entities` to use `mentioned` to know whenever the bot was mentioned.