# How can my chatbot (MS Botframework) ignore messages where not mentioned in a Slack channel? bot

Tags: node.js, botframework, slack, azure-language-understanding

I'm developing a chatbot using the Micrososft Botframework for NodeJS - LUIS.ai and integrating this in Slack, using dialogs.  Right now the bot works fine on a DM window, however when added to a slack channel the bot replies to all the messages even when not mentioned.

I know the bot should be able to listen all the messages, but how can I define programmaticaly to only interact in a slack channel only when mentioned?

Is there a way to identify if the conversation is from a channel or from a direct message?

This is piece sample piece of code of the Dialogs

```
            bot.dialog('intentName', [
                function (session, args, next) {
                    var intent = args.intent;
                    session.dialogData.item = {};
                    var item= builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(intent.entities, 'myEntity');
                    session.dialogData.itemNumber = item.entity;

                    // Prompt for title
                    if (!session.dialogData.item) {
                        builder.Prompts.text(session, 'What are you looking for?');
                    } else {
                        next();
                    }
                },
                function (session, results, next) {
                    if (results.response) {
                        session.dialogData.itemNumber = results.response;
                    }
                     //restify call
                     //session.send(response)
                      session.endDialog();
                    });
                }
            ]).triggerAction({
                matches: 'intentName'
            });
```

*********** UPDATE ***********

I was able to identify between a channel conversation and a DM using this piece of code

```
if(session.message.address.channelId=="slack"){
            //Channel conversation
            if(session.message.address.conversation.isGroup){

                if(session.message.text.includes("@botname")){

                   //your code

                }
                session.endDialog();
                //bot not mentioned, hence do nothing
            }
    else{
           //your bot reply to a DM
     }
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get my bot to ignore conversation until it is addressed directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39649451/how-can-i-get-my-bot-to-ignore-conversation-until-it-is-addressed-directly)

Comment: The one I marked as a duplicate is basically the opposite but you will get the point of where to look.

Comment: @EzequielJadib  but how can you identify if the message comes from a DM or from a channel, of course in the DM there is no mention so the session.message.entities is empty

Comment: @JorgeGarcia if(session.message.address.channelId != "slack" || session.message.text.includes('@botid')) { }

Comment: @JorgeGarcia you can try checking session.message.address.conversation.isGroup

Comment: Thanks! I was able to make i work with using this:        if(session.message.address.channelId=="slack"){
            //Channel conversation
            if(session.message.address.conversation.isGroup){

                if(session.message.text.includes("@botname")){